# adding lines to scatterplot with automatic coloring

Tags: vba, excel, macros, scatter-plot

I have a macro that can create a scatter plot and add several sets of data. all the data series have different colors and markers automatically, now i want to add lines that connect the point and have the auto coloring also, instead it makes all the lines black. Is there a way to have it turn the lines on with the automatic coloring so they match the markers? I recorded myself manually changing one of the black lines to auto coloring but when I add this line to my macro it still makes all the lines black. And I can't manually enter a color code because each time i run this it may add a different number of data sets.

```
Adds Stage trends to plot
x = Cells(1, 1).Value
y = Cells(3, 1).Value
y = y + 13
a = 4
b = 2
Do
stg = Cells(1, a).Value
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(b).Name = stg
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(b).XValues = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(x, 2))
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(b).Values = Range(Cells(2, a), Cells(x, a))
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(b).Select
Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
a = a + 1
b = b + 1
Loop Until a = y
```

Note this is only part of the code but it covers what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

After reviewing the code in you file provided I went about the problem a little differently.

Change `xlXYScatter` to `xlXYScatterSmooth` on this line

```
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
```

---

After your series loop add the following code to remove the line from the first series.

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works for me when I use your code snippet.  Can you share your excel file, for some dumbed-down version of it, with full code?

Comment: Did you run this in a loop so it creates adds multiple series, one after another?

Comment: Yes, I used your exact code and added data to sheet to graph.  Once working, I re-wrote to use `With` statement to make it a little more readable.

Comment: Is it possible to attach the worksheet on this forum?

Comment: I used Lines instead of Smooth but that works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: Great, glad you got it working.  Kind of odd problem with setting the colors independently.  Hadn't come across that before.  Cheers